# Changing Enumerate Colors using Beamer Theme Berlin

Tags: beamer, lists, color, enumerate, themes

I am trying to figure out how to change the coloring of enumerations in Beamer using the Theme 'Berlin'. I was able to change the color of the Itemize environment by:

```
    \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=TAMIU}
```

Also I was able to change the color of the Table of Content enumeration by:

```
    \setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=TAMIU,fg=white}
```

But non of these two approaches work for the enumeration:

```
    \setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=TAMIU}
    \setbeamercolor{enumerate number projected}{bg=Tamiu,fg=white}
```

So how can I do this?

Comment: Hi Martin, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I edited your post to remove the thanks- it may seem strange, but the best way to thank people is to 'upvote' and accept appropriate answers :) It's generally best to provide a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that folks don't have to re-create your problem from scratch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `enumerate number projected` template. Try instead

```
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=white,bg=TAMIU}
```

which will also take care of `section number projected` in one go.

Comment: That is exactly, what I have been looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You can change the color by using a copy of the definition of the `enumerate item` template for the `square` option, as given in the file `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`. A little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}
{
  \hbox{%
    \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[olive!30]{item projected}% original: [bg]
    \vrule width2.25ex height1.85ex depth.4ex%
    \hskip-2.25ex%
    \hbox to2.25ex{%
      \hfil%
      \color{red!60!black}\insertenumlabel% original: [fg]
      \hfil}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]